# next-mdx-remote doesn't pass the component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

I'm using [next-mdx-remote](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote)

in mdx file

```
- Use `RAND()` in
```

in a react component

```
import { MDXRemote } from 'next-mdx-remote'
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize'

const content = await serialize(content, {
  mdxOptions: {
    remarkPlugins: [],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
  scope: frontmatter,
}),

<MDXRemote {...content} components={{
  code: ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => (
    <code className="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800" children={children} />
  ),
}} />
```

The result, output HTML

```
<li>
  Use 
  <code>
    RAND()
  </code> 
  in
</li>
```

It should be `<code class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800">` but it doesn't.

I'm not sure why, and other tags like `<p class="...">` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using single back-tick code (inline code) you should use `inlineCode` to target it. `code`/`pre` targets code blocks that use triple back-ticks.

```js
<MDXRemote {...content} components={{
    inlineCode: ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => (
        <code className="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800" children={children} />
    )
}} />
```